# Listing numbers whose digit sum is greater or equal 5

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, replacement, digits

I just started using Mathematica and at the moment I'm learning some things.

As you can see in the headline, I want to make a list of numbers (up to 100) whose digit sum is greater or equal 5.

I started with

```
Select[Total[IntegerDigits[Range[100]], {2}], GreaterThan[4]]
```

that leads to the following list:

```
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, \
9, 10, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, \
12, 13, 14, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, \
13, 14, 15, 16, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 9, 10, 11, 12, \
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
```

So now I have the list of all digit sums meeting my requirement. But how do I use it to list up the numbers which belong to them? I wanted to use it to overwrite the "wrong" numbers with a "nothing". Or am I using a much too difficult way?

Thank you in advance! I hope my English is good enough to at least understand what I want to do

Comment: `Select[Range[100], Total@IntegerDigits@# > 4 &]`

Comment: Yet another way: `x /. FindInstance[Mod[x, 10] + Quotient[x, 10] >= 5 && 0 <= x < 100, 
  x, Integers, 100]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[{ints = Range[100]},
 Pick[ints, Clip[Total[IntegerDigits[ints], {2}], {-∞, 5}], 5]]
```

Using `Nothing`:

```
With[{ints = Range[100]},
 ints /. Thread[PositionIndex[Clip[Total[IntegerDigits[ints], {2}], {4, ∞}]][4] -> Nothing]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way using "nothing" to replace that, too? Or is it much too complicate?

Comment: @Beggi01 Added a nothing version

Comment: Can't use the option to thank you - so: Thank you very much!